# My discord.py discord bot keeps getting throttled by the Discord API/Cloudflare

Tags: python

Basically, my bot randomly gets banned for "exceeding the Discord API Ratelimits", but it accesses the Discord API once every HOUR. I host my bot on Replit. There is a 429 Too many requests error, and here are some of the error messages.

Access denied | discord.com used Cloudflare to restrict access.

The owner of this website (discord.com) has banned you temporarily from accessing this website.

The entire error message is written in HTML and it is just plopped into the Replit console, which makes it hard to read for me. Any help would be appreciated!

```
def getguildcount(guildid): #GETS guild member count from Hypixel API
  with open("serverchannel.json", "r") as read_file:
    data = json.load(read_file)
    global guildname
    guildname = data[guildid]['guildname']
  data = requests.get(
      url = f'https://api.hypixel.net/guild?key=NOT IMPORTANT&name={guildname}',
        params = {
            "key": "NOT IMPORTANT"
        }
    ).json()
      
  guild = data['guild']
  guild = guild['members']
  
  membercount = len(guild)
  return membercount
  
def getservercount(): #gets member count in the discord server
  for guild in bot.guilds:
    membercount = guild.member_count
    return membercount
    
def getdiscchannel(guildid):  #gets discord channel from json file
  with open("serverchannel.json", "r") as read_file:
    data = json.load(read_file)
    return data[guildid]['discchannel']

def getguildchannel(guildid):  #gets guild channel from json file
  with open("serverchannel.json", "r") as read_file:
    data = json.load(read_file)
    return data[guildid]['guildchannel']
    
async def countermainloop(): #loop that consistently updates channels
  while True:
    for guild in bot.guilds:
      discordmemb = bot.get_channel(getdiscchannel(f'{guild.id}'))
      guildmemb = bot.get_channel(getguildchannel(f'{guild.id}'))
  
  
      guildmembers=getguildcount(f'{guild.id}')      #gets guild member count
      discmembers=getservercount() #gets discord member count


      #edits both channels
      await discordmemb.edit(name=f'Discord Members: {discmembers}')
      await guildmemb.edit(name=f'Guild Members: {guildmembers}')
  

      #Logs Changes in Console 
      tz_Ch = pytz.timezone('America/Chicago') 
      time_Ch = datetime.now(tz_Ch)
      time = time_Ch.strftime("%H:%M:%S")    
      print(f'updated with {discmembers} discord members and {guildmembers} guild members at {time} CST in guild {guildname}')
    await asyncio.sleep(3600)
```

Comment: Most likely you are being ratelimited because of your while loop. Generally doing X every N is likely to get you temporarily or permanently banned from any API.

Comment: Is there any way I can automatically update it? I have seen other bots do such things...

Comment: Should I like... randomize how long it waits for?

Comment: That would probably help, but also extending the amount of time that it waits between loops would also help

Comment: Also look at discord.ext.tasks for built-in looping function

Comment: Ooh, I'll check that. Thank you :D